# Execute stored procedure DBI Perl

Tags: sql-server, perl, dbi

I need to use a stored procedure to gather some data from a database and for that, I've been provided with a sql code:

```
declare @p3 xml
set @p3=convert(xml,N'<root><r i="XXXXXXXXXXXX"/></root>')
declare @p8 xml
set @p8=convert(xml,N'<root><r i="274"/><r i="276"/><r i="275"/><r i="155"/><r i="20"/><r i="520"/><r i="758"/><r i="760"/><r i="156"/><r i="172"/></root>')
exec spu_SearchItems @siteName=N'XXXXXXXXXXXX',@searchString=N'*',@searchLocations=@p3,@includeChildren=0,@includeSearchLocations=0,@includeExtensions=0,@maxResults=501,@classIds=@p8
```

I've replaced sensitive data with XXXXXXXXXXXX. This query works when used in Microsoft SQL Management Studio and it fetches everything that I need to.

My issue is that when I execute this same code on my perl script, it returns a hash reference, what leads me to think that either the I'm not using the sql statement properly or that I'm not being able to "read" the info back.

I'm using this for setting up the sql statement:

```
sub newquery {

    my $sql = q(declare @p3 xml
        set @p3=convert(xml,N'<root><r i="XXXXXXXXXXXX"/></root>')
        declare @p8 xml
        set @p8=convert(xml,N'<root><r i="274"/><r i="276"/><r i="275"/><r i="155"/><r i="20"/><r i="520"/><r i="758"/><r i="760"/><r i="156"/><r i="172"/></root>')
        exec spu_SearchItems @siteName=N'XXXXXXXXXXXX',@searchString=N'*',@searchLocations=@p3,@includeChildren=0,@includeSearchLocations=0,@includeExtensions=0,@maxResults=501,@classIds=@p8);

    &dbMasterSub($sql);
}
```

and this for calling to the database.

```
sub dbMasterSub() {

    my $sql = shift;
    my @row;

    # print $sql."\n";
    my $port = 1443;
    my $dsn  = "Provider=sqloledb;Trusted Connection=yes;";

    $dsn .= "Server=" . $myServer . ";Database=$myDB;";

    eval {
        my $dbh = DBI->connect( "dbi:ADO:$dsn", $myUser, $myPass, { RaiseError => 1, AutoCommit => 1 } );
        my $sth;

        if ( $sql eq "ping" ) {
            my $ping = $dbh->ping();
            return $ping;
        }
        else {
            $sth = $dbh->prepare( $sql );

            #Execute the statement
            $sth->execute();

            print "sth -> $sth\n";

            open( my $fh, '>:encoding(UTF-8)', $tagsPaths );
            print $fh "{\n";
            my $index = 0;

            while ( my $row = $sth->fetchrow_array() ) {

                print "$row" . "\n";

                if ( $index == 0 ) {
                    print $fh $row;
                    $index = $index + 1;
                }
                else {
                    print $fh ",\n" . $row;
                }
            }

            print $fh "\n}";
            close $fh;

            $sth->finish();
        }

        $dbh->disconnect();
    };
}
```

Also, I've tried to use fetchrow_hashref() instead of fetchrow_array(), but that makes no difference at all.

Hope you can point me on the right direction. Thanks.

**EDIT:** I've runned the query on MS SQL and it returns 3 results set. Result set 1 is what I need, but don't know how to get to it.

Comment: Is this a *Microsoft SQL Server* database?

Comment: It is Microsoft SQL, but I'm not sure if Server.

Comment: Don't call subroutines with `&` and don't declare them with empty prototypes if they actually take arguments (`sub dbMasterSub()`).

Comment: So, the correct way to do that will be call the subrutines like dbMasterSub(param) and declare them as sub dbMasterSub {, right?

Comment: @LuisDiaz Yes, exactly.

Comment: [The documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#fetchrow_array) says not to call `fetchrow_array` in scalar context. What are you trying to do there?

Comment: It's a code that a partner passed me, and it's like this. I've used this a lot of times to fetch rows from others tables and databases and there is no problem at all. Anyway, will modified it according to the documentation

Comment: I would replace this with `my @rows = $sth->fetchrow_array; print $fh join(",\n", @rows);` which seems much shorter and easier to understand

Comment: already did that, but that is not the problem hahaha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to be able to iterate and gather all the data returned from the stored procedure using this code:

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute();
my $more_results;
my $count = 0;
my $tinyIndex = 0;
do{
    $count++;
    print "\n\tdataset $count\n";

    my $names = $sth ->{NAME};
    print join(";",@$names),"\n";
    while (my @row = $sth->fetchrow_array()){
        print join(";",@row),"\n";
        $tinyIndex++;
    }
    if ($@) {
        print "FAILED\n$@";
    }
    print "$tinyIndex rows\n";
}while($more_results = $sth->more_results);
```

being $sql a variable that holds the procedure itself.